# changing css of SVG not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

so i have two 'inline' svgs one for male and other for female. I have embedded them in HTML bu `including` the php file. I have two buttons "male" and "female" each to show the respective SVG on click. By default the visible SVG is male and on clicking female button it changes the css property `visibility` of male to hidden and female to visible and vice versa.

However the fill color of female `<path id="base"/>` doesnot change on button click however fill color of male `<path id="base"/>` changes perfectly. The awkward thing is that both have the same `id="base"` and by changing the color i am changing the color of ID.

Sample SVG Code of both files

```
<path id="base" d="M105.321,475.585c0..."/>
<path id="collor" d="M207.452,17.68c..."/>
```

other SVG also has path with id "base" and "collor" but they dont change.

This is how i change color

```
$('#whiteB').click(function(){
        $('#base').css('fill', 'white');
        $('#collor').css('fill', 'yellow'); 
    });
```

I know this has something to do with the fact that I'm changing the visibility or anything but its awkward so help me out.

Comment: use `base_m` for male, and `base_f` for female. selectors work only as far as first occurrence of the id.

Answer (score 0):

Having two XML items with the same ID is not valid.  You will not be able to target the second instance with a duplicate ID.  ID's should be unique.  If you want an attribute to be the same between elements you would use a class.  Without knowing the rest of your code, you would do something like this:

```
<path class="base" d="M105.321,475.585c0..."/>
<path class="collor" d="M207.452,17.68c..."/>
```

JS:

```
$('.genderButton').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.base').css('fill', 'white');
    $(this).find('.collor').css('fill', 'yellow'); 
});
```

With the assumption that `genderButton` is the class of the buttons that you click on.

Comment: Wow i am so stupid. I was targeting the ID. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same ID twice, jquery will only ever find the first occurrence in the document.

As others mentioned you should really use classes or unique ID's but this isn't always feasible. Especially if the SVG are hugely complicated or embedded from an external source.

If you cant change the ID's for whatever reason, you can point JQuery in the right direction by limiting the scope of the selector to a parent element.

In your case you could give each SVG tag or a parent element a unique ID and use that ID to limit the scope of your JQuery selector.

Your markup would become something like this:

```
<svg id="male">
    <path id="base" />
</svg>

<svg id="female">
    <path id="base" />
</svg>
```

Your JQuery to target the female svg would become:

```
$('#whiteB').click(function(){
    $('#female #base').css('fill', 'white');
    $('#collor').css('fill', 'yellow'); 
});
```

[Here is a demo of the concept working](http://jsfiddle.net/mLf52btm/2/)